# Change UITableViewCell background color without animation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Changing of cell background color have some weird animation. I want to change this color immediately without animation. Maybe I should override `setBackgroundColor` method in subclass somehow?

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably that you are changing that color while a UIView animation is in progress (a transition, a tableView row update, a UIView animation block, etc).

Try the following:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}];
```

**UPDATE:** I'm not sure what kind of animation you got though.  I made a [simple test UITableViewController](https://gist.github.com/simondec/000e06969bb9e3597e92) that change the cell color without animation when you tap on them (using what you specified in your comment), and it works.

Comment: It's not helped, really. I update row when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` called. I deselect row immediately `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:false];` and call `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`

Comment: @user1561346 I updated my answer with a test that change the background color of cells without animation.  I'm not sure what kind of animation you got?